# capture and save continious image in Android

Tags: android

this is my code it  store captured picture form camera and save it on the **SDcard** but Now i want to enhance this code to taking pictures every 5 seconds  If any body having an idea how to do this ,please share

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {


    private final int requestCode = 20;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        int pictureCounter = 10;

        imageHolder = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.captured_photo);
        Button capturedImageButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.photo_button);
        capturedImageButton.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent photoCaptureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                startActivityForResult(photoCaptureIntent, requestCode);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if(this.requestCode == requestCode && resultCode == RESULT_OK){
            Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap)data.getExtras().get("data");

            String partFilename = currentDateFormat();
            storeCameraPhotoInSDCard(bitmap, partFilename);


        }
    }

    private String currentDateFormat(){
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HH_mm_ss");
        String  currentTimeStamp = dateFormat.format(new Date());
        return currentTimeStamp;
    }

    private void storeCameraPhotoInSDCard(Bitmap bitmap, String currentDate){
        File outputFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "photo_" + currentDate + ".jpg");
        try {
            FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fileOutputStream);
            fileOutputStream.flush();
            fileOutputStream.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should implement a runnable interface that uses threads. This way you could call the function on the OnClick method, then call Thread.sleep(timeinmilliseconds), then call the function inside the onClick method again, as many times as needed.

Here is an example of how to use threads:

http://www.wideskills.com/java-tutorial/java-threads-tutorial

Comment: 1. At the top of your class add implements runnable. 2.Create a thread. 3.call method 4.call thread.sleep() 5. Call method again

Comment: can you send me your email please  !